# Multiple validation on one field Yup

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm validating a field by using YUP as validator, but I already made an test in it, and i'm having trouble to add another validation.

I validate this:

```
nome: Yup.string()
            .required(Mensagens.CAMPO_OBRIGATORIO)
            .test('teste-nome-igual',Mensagens.NOME_NAO_DEVE_SER_IGUAL,function(value){
                let check = []
                if(contatos.length > 0)
                    check = contatos.map((contato)=> contato.nome.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()) 
                return !check.includes(true)
            }),
```

But I also want to validate if the field `nome` doesn't contain any non ASCII caracters, and if so, show a message that it can't contain, things that aren't letters.

Comment: just chain another `test` method

Comment: I've tried that, it didn't work, could you show me an example of that? maybe I dit it wrong

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can chain `test` multiple times as `test` returns the schema. Like:

```
Yup.string()
   .required(Mensagens.CAMPO_OBRIGATORIO)
   .test('teste-nome-igual',
         Mensagens.NOME_NAO_DEVE_SER_IGUAL,
         function(value){
           let check = []
           if(contatos.length > 0)
             check = contatos.map((contato)=> contato.nome.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()) 
           return !check.includes(true)
         }
   )
   .test('test ascii',
         "Nome shouldn't contain non-ascii chars",
         (value) => {
         // test for ascii chars here and return true or false.
        }
   )
```

Comment: How would I call the field "nome" inside of the test itself?

Comment: Do you want to access value of `nome` in test?